# convert stamp to varchar and use it in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

guys i created stored procedure to synchronize my data in a table from the main database to the branches using C# service using a last stamp. in the stored procedure i converted the stamp of the main database to varchar **select @CurrentStamp = convert(varchar, value) from parameter where id = 3** this stamp i should get it in the C# as an output and send it as parameter to the stored procedure in the branch save the data that should i synchronize then save this stamp in a parameter table as varchar. all by testing without using the soap service. when i tried to use it in the soap service it throws an exception **hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character** . any help please i tried to convert it to varbinary but it keep changing the stamp to another value. if any one knows how to let the XML read this values without exception please help.

```
FamilyService.FamilyService fs = new FamilyService.FamilyService();
DataSet ds = fs.GetFamilyToSynchronize(Current.LoggedUserSchool.ID, stamp, out currentStamp);
```

-

```
public static DataSet GetFamilyToSynchronize(int schoolID, string stamp, out string CurrentStamp)
    {
        DataTable dtFamilyToSynchronize = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtFamilyPhones = new DataTable();
        CurrentStamp = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            using (DataBaseClass db = new DataBaseClass())
            {
                db.Connect();
                SqlCommand command = db.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "GetFamilyToSynchronize";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolID", schoolID);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stamp", stamp);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentStamp", CurrentStamp);
                command.Parameters["@CurrentStamp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                command.Parameters["@CurrentStamp"].Size = 255;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(ds);
                CurrentStamp = command.Parameters["@CurrentStamp"].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex){Logger.LogException(ex);}

        return ds;
    }
```

SQL Stored Procedure

```
GO
ALTER Proc [dbo].[GetFamilyToSynchronize] (@SchoolID int , @Stamp varchar(255) = null, @CurrentStamp varchar(255) output) as

select @CurrentStamp = convert(varchar, value) from parameter where id = 3

SELECT f.*
into #tmpFamily
FROM [Family] f
inner join fatherschools fs on fs.FamilyID =  f.ID
where f.id  =f.fatherlinkid --not in (select FatherLinkID from family )
and schoolID = @SchoolID
and (@Stamp is null or f.stamp> convert(timestamp, isnull(@Stamp,'')))

select distinct f.id, phonetypeid,phonenumber, t.FatherLinkID
from familyphones f
inner join #tmpFamily t on t.ID = f.FamilyID

select * from #tmpFamily
```

Comment: Your error is occurring because the database is returning null (hex 0). Check that your stored procedure is returning a valid value.

Comment: the idea is to get the timestamp from the database converted from timestamp to varchar i know that it is returning null(hex 0) and i need it as it. any solution for that?

Comment: Add a coalesce or isnull to your @currentstamp line, and coalesce it to an empty string. Your soap service will have to know what to do with an empty string, but null is an invalid character in a soap string.

Comment: as a note: you do know that `TIMESTAMP` is not a `DATETIME` data type but rather just a binary value that is used for version-stamping. In new SQL-Server it is being called `rowversion`

Comment: @paqogomez i need to send it as it i want it to synchronize the data second time starting from this stamp. the data in my database is very large and i can't sync it all every time.

Comment: Your problem is that you are treating Datetime values as varchar's.  If you change to a datetime value, then you would 1) never get a null back and 2) be able to say "give me everything the first time, but only from last update the second time."